# Android Studio shows every line of code with lint -compile- error

Tags: android, android-studio

What the heck.  My app worked yesterday.  Today, every line of code has a lint error, including my imports.  Mostly "cannot resolve ...."

```
cannot resolve symbol TextView
cannot resolve symbol Intent
...
...
```

Weirdly, I can still run my program to an emulator and it seemingly works fine.
This is what I tried.

- Cleaning project
- Rebuilding project
- Syncing project
- Updating Android Studio
- Restating Android studio
- Closing project and reopening

**Update:**
i have this note in my layout preview

> NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.

I really don't know how to start trouble shooting this issue

**Update 2**
I am dying here.  I reinstalled both Java and Android Studio.  I believe I have the path for JDK and SDK correct.  I tried a new project... wouldn't compile.. same thing.  I appreciate any advice. [image]

**SOLUTION YEAH !!**

"File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart"

Comment: These are compiler errors, not lint errors. It sounds like somehow the SDK settings were changed in Android Studio. (Note that you can still run your app if you have lint errors. On the other hand, compiler errors will not allow you to run your app.)

Comment: any suggestions on where to start.

Comment: Open the Android Studio project settings and make sure your Android SDK is correct and the Java JDK didn't get deleted/upgraded to a new path

Comment: Thank you so much for the help so far.  You seem to be pointing me in the right direction, I just really don't know what to look for.  I opened an older version of the project... same issue.  Would uninstalling / installing Android Studio clear up what ever setting has changed?

Comment: Doubt it. There was a recent Java upgrade. Your JDK settings might have changed and that is an external installer from Android Studio

Comment: I've updated again.  Save me please :)

Comment: You can post your solution as an actual answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Whew!

"File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart"